# Why is webpack not updating bundle file with dev server?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I've added the publicPath to the output as mentioned in the docs, but when I make changes to the ts code while I am running webpack dev server (using the command `yarn webpack-dev-server`), I can see it recompile and the logs update in the terminal, but no new changes are saved to my bundle.js file.

If I run `yarn webpack` command tho, it *does* work as expected though, leading me to believe it is not a path issue.

Any idea what I could be missing?

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: "ts-loader", 
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src")],
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: "public", 
    filename: "bundle.js", 
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"), 
  },
};
```

These are my dependency version:

- ts-loader: 9.4.2,
- typescript: 4.9.5,
- webpack: 5.75.0,
- webpack-cli: 5.0.1,
- webpack-dev-server: 4.11.1

Comment: Is it saved at `public/bundle.js`?

Comment: @ShSvyatoslav yep it is

Comment: I think it is the development mode, it works in memory as I know

Comment: you can use devServer in production mode

Comment: @ShSvyatoslav I added devServer and it works with that, thank you! :)

Comment: Glad if worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `devServer` in `production` mode, otherwise webpack will generate `bundle.js` in memory